# Use QT MainWindow in worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have to manage a MainWindow updated by more udp channel messages. Furthermore, reading a configuration file, i have to show or not main window and if not manage/dispatch/filter the udp messages to another application. Is it possible to define an engine class that manages communication and updates Mainwindow if it is shown? How can i manage Mainwindow? Maybe use a singleton?
What i would do (pseudo code):

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Engine app();
    app.run();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Engine.cpp

```
Engine::Engine( QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent)
{
   show_mainwindow = false;
   thread          = new QThread();
   Worker          = new Worker();

   // Filter/Dispatch
   Worker->moveToThread(thread);
   connect(Worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
   connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), Worker, SLOT(process()));
   connect(Worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
   connect(Worker, SIGNAL(finished()), Worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
   connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
   thread->start();

   // Message Receiver (more)
   UdpRecvr = new Receiver();
   connect(UdpRecvr, SIGNAL(receivedMsg(const QByteArray)), udpManager, SLOT(processMsg(const QByteArray)));

     //Mainwindow Singleton used to update with SIGNAL/SLOT
     WINDOWINSTANCE = MainWindow::GetInstance();

    if(show_mainwindow)
    {
        WINDOWISTANCE->show();
    }
}
```

Also in UdpRecvr class i would use MainWindow Singleton. I have read that using singleton with SIGNAL/SLOT is thread-safe. Is this a proper design solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not recommended to use thread worker. Better if you use thread based on the task (check QtConcurrent)

Answer (score 0):

I usually start a dialoguing thread in the MainWindow and connect worker's SIGNALs to window's SLOTs.

```
void MainGUI::startServerSockets() {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(cfg_robotPort);
    //serverSocket->setDebugLevel(debugLevel);
    ssocketThread = new QThread(this);
    connect(ssocketThread, SIGNAL(started()), serverSocket, SLOT(run()));
    connect(ssocketThread, SIGNAL(finished()), serverSocket, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    connect(serverSocket, SIGNAL(socketRead(const QString &)), this, SLOT(robotSocketRead(const QString &)));

    serverSocket->moveToThread(ssocketThread);
    ssocketThread->start();
}
```

In the worker you can check if the MainWindow is visible and then rise the SIGNAL, otherwise dialogue with the other application.